# How to print the information of all tables using Oracle?

Tags: oracle

I'm studying DDBB and we are using Oracle. Using too much tables can be really difficult for me because I have to remember table1.content2, table3.content1, etc.

So because of that, I would like to print (in paper) the header tables to make it easier.

I know my explanation is not very good so I tried to "draw it" below:

select * from user_tables;

↓

```
table_name|
-----------
table1    |
-----------
table2    |
-----------
table3    |
```

What I want:

```
table1
-----------------------------
content1| content2| content3|

table2
-----------------------------
content1| content2| content3|

table3
-----------------------------
content1| content2| content3|
```

How can I get this in paper?

Thanks!

Comment: If you have Oracle SQLDeveloper, you can get the pictorial representation of your schema/tables/columns. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/datamodeler/overview/index.html?ssSourceSiteId=otnru Even better?

Comment: What exactly is `content1` to be? If you want to show the content of the tables you potentially have may rows for each table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a describe using SQLplus or SQL Developer: `desc myschema.mytable` This way you'll also see the column's datatype and whether it can be null or not.

```
desc myschema.category

Name           Null     Type           
-------------- -------- -------------- 
CATEGORY_ID    NOT NULL NUMBER(38)     
CATEGORY       NOT NULL VARCHAR2(40)   
SUBCATEGORY             VARCHAR2(40)   
MOD_DT         NOT NULL DATE
```

If you want the fields listed horizontally, try `select * from myschema.mytable where rownum = 1` This will bring you back one row, with all the column names listed on one line, although they may be spaced out considerably. This way, you'd also have a row of sample data.

```
select * from myschema.category where rownum = 1;

CATEGORY_ID            CATEGORY                                 SUBCATEGORY                              MOD_DT                   
---------------------- ---------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------- -------------------------
28                     My Category                              My Subcategory                           18-MAR-14 13:41.27
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're a student and can't install SQL Developer locally, maybe you could use SQuirreL SQL, a more lightweight (but still excellent) JDBC database client. I've not used the graphical stuff which I believe they have, but you can just simply navigate the tree like structures through the tables and easily get any info you may want, table structure, row count and data.